# Python 3: ошибка 'name '...' is not defined"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу сделать некий "автостатус" для бота, использу. для этого str(status_message_from_cycle) выставляя ему значение в цикле:

```
def status_cycle1():
    status_message_from_cycle = str("test 1")

def status_cycle2():
    status_message_from_cycle = str("test 2")

interval = 2

def statusPeriodicFunction():
    status_cycle1()
    status_cycle2()

def startTimer():
    threading.Timer(interval, startTimer).start()
    statusPeriodicFunction()
```

Позже это значение выставляется в конфиге:

```
self.status_message = str(status_message_from_cycle)
```

Но после интерпретаций кода выходит:

> File "/media/mint/F3D8-BADB/MusicBot/musicbot/config.py", line 88, in **init**
>       self.status_message = str(status_message_from_cycle)
>   NameError: name 'status_message_from_cycle' is not defined

Comment: Вы инициализируете переменную `status_message_from_cycle` в функции, следовательно она доступна только в этой функции (в локальной области видимости). Код за пределами функции не имеет доступ к этой переменной, она не определена в глобальной области видимости, о чём Вам и говорит ошибка: `name is not defined`.

Comment: IMHO, архитектуру Вашего кода нужно сильно переработать. Я мог бы сказать, что решением проблемы будет добавлении строки `global status_message_from_cycle`, но на деле это сделает ещё больше проблем. Лучше, чтобы функции **возвращали** значение.

Comment: @nomnoms12 благодарю, но к сожалению я не предпологаю, как можно определить переменную в глобалбном плане (3 день изучения).

Comment: @Troit5kiy Поищете, пожалуйста, по следующим запросам: _"Python namespaces"_ (_"Python области видимости"_). Если кратко, то всё зависит от того, где Вы определяете переменную: переменные из функций недоступны "снаружи" этих самых функций. А чтобы принудительно объявить переменную в глобальной области видимости, есть оператор `global` (моветон!).

Comment: Прочитай про **области видимости!** Ты вызываешь локальную переменную в функции, которая не может быть видна вне функции. Чтобы исправить это просто объяви переменную вне функции(можешь придать рандомное значение).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В питон область видимости переменной по умолчанию локальная. К примеру следующий код не изменит глобальную переменную

```
var_a = "original value"

def modify_var_a():
  var_a = "changed value" # создана новая переменная

modify_var_a()
print(var_a) # >>> original value
```

Чтобы явно указать использование переменной из внешней области видимости нужно использовать ключевое слово `global` с названием переменной до того, как она будет использована во внутренней области видимости. Если же есть несколько вложенных областей видимости, то можно получить доступ либо к глобальной области видимости при помощи `global`, либо же к "ближайшей" используя `nonlocal`.

```
var_a = 1

def modify_a():
  var_a = 2 # другая переменная с тем же именем, что и глобальная

  def modify_a1():
    global var_a
    var_a = 3

  modify_a1()

  def modify_a2():
    nonlocal var_a
    var_a = 5

  modify_a2()

  print("modify_a::var_a =", var_a)

modify_a()
print("::var_a =", var_a)
```

> modify_a::var_a = 5
>   ::var_a = 3

Это же происходит и в вашем случае. В функции `status_cycle1` создаётся новая переменная `status_message_from_cycle` но она не выходит за область видимости функции. Нужно сначала создать глобальную, затем в функции указать, что используется именно глобальная, а затем её модифицировать.